# The password is not encrypted at django admin login page

Tags: django, django-admin

Hello I started using django framework recently. One thing that is bothering me is when I login from admin page. The password is being sent in plain text format without any encryption. Is it normal? IMHO shouldn't the password be encrypted before sent over network?

Comment: No. This is the expected behavior; every framework works like this. That's the reason that nowadays https is required for all login pages; to avoid sending the password over plain text.

Answer (score 1):

What would encrypt the password? The browser would.

What built-in encryption exists for the browser? TLS/SSL.

How to activate that encryption? By using https instead of http.

That would result in the communication between the browser and the server being encrypted.

In prod environment you can use [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) to create an SSL certificate. Your local Dev environment does not need it.